# How to use python3 asyncio to do, well, async io?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await

My python 3.6 program needs to write some files asynchronously, so that
it can overlap the writing with computation on another thread.
The program uses a C module library to compute a structure, and it calls a 
function in that library to save it. Below is a sketch:

```py
async def save_thing(thing_ref):
    my_lib.save_thing(thing_ref)

def main():
    handles = []
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        thing_ref = my_lib.compute_thing(i)
        handle = save_thing(thing_ref)
        handles.append(handle)

    await_all(handles)
    # ... proceed with program ...
```

`mylib.save_thing` releases the GIL: on entry it calls `PyEval_SaveThread()` and
 on exit it calls `PyEval_RestoreThread()`. I omitted, above, explicitly
 incrementing a ref count on `thing_ref`, but I expect I'll manage ref 
 counts explictly to keep the `thing_ref` alive until `save_thing` is done.

Could someone please help me flesh out that sketch, to show me the machinery I
 need to include to make the body of my_lib.save_thing() execute concurrently, on another thread, 
 with the python loop? I'm fumbling around trying to understand the roles
 of event loops, the `asyncio` module, the GIL, and python threading generally. I suspect simply releasing the GIL doesn't cause the main thread interpreter to resume at that point,
and I'm unclear how to get it do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and save_thing(thing_ref) is  awaitable 
then you can do this

```
import asyncio



async def save_thing(thing_ref):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)                # so you can see this works
    # await my_lib.save_thing(thing_ref)  # if this is awaitable
    return thing_ref


def compute_thing(i):
    return i




def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    handles = []
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        thing_ref = compute_thing(i)
        handle = loop.run_until_complete(save_thing(thing_ref))
        handles.append(handle)
    print(handles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output

> > > [1, 2, 3]